# Specflow. Parametrized tests

Tags: c#, .net, automated-tests, specflow

I have such user story:

```
Given I am on the 'Login page'
When I enter following credentials
     |Email |Pass |
     |email1|pass1|
     |email2|pass2|
Then I get next 'Error' messages
     |ErrorMessage |
     |ErrorMessage1|
     |ErrorMessage2|
```

How can this be done?
The problem is that by my implementation, web driver is entering all the credentials from first table, and then try to assert error messages, but I need test to be run multiple times(kind of a loop).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use a [scenario outline](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Using-Gherkin-Language-in-SpecFlow#scenario-outlines):

```
Scenario Outline: some name...
    Given I am on the 'Login page'
    When I enter the email <email> and password <password>
    Then I get next the error message <errorMessage>
Examples:
    | email | password | errorMessage |
    | email1| pass1    | ErrorMessage1|
    | email2| pass2    | ErrorMessage2|
```

this will run the same test twice, once for each row in the `Examples` table. If you want the test to be run more times, just add more rows to the `Examples` table

As was pointed out in the comments, `Examples` is the defined term in gerkin, but `Scenarios` or `Examples` works fine in SpecFlow

Comment: The keyword is ````Examples```` instead of ````Scenarios````. Proposed an edit.

Comment: @paulroho either is acceptable, at least in SpecFlow  [see this](https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin/blob/master/lib/gherkin/i18n.json) for the definitions which are mapped, which is `"examples": "Examples|Scenarios"`, but updated for clarity. Thanks!